# What is difference between MediaItem and MediaSource in Exoplayer?

Tags: exoplayer2.x

When you are initializing exoplayer, you need to initialize `MediaItem` and give it URI of media source.
But so what is MediaSource?

Answer (score 4):

According to https://exoplayer.dev/ website:

In `ExoPlayer` every piece of media is represented by a `MediaItem`. However internally, the player needs `MediaSource` instances to play the content. The player creates these from media items using a `MediaSourceFactory`.

for more details:
https://exoplayer.dev/media-items.html

Answer (score -1):

In Exoplayer, each **media** is considered as a `MediaItem`, which can be conveniently built using `MediaItem.Builder`. This media item is not playable until it is converted into `MediaSource`. For playing medias in player, media items are converted into `MediaSource`s. This task is done using a `MediaSource.Factory`.

Aforesaid conversion is carried out by a `DefaultMediaSourceFactory` if default configuration is not changed.

For more information, please check out: https://exoplayer.dev/media-items.html